# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toISOString')

Tags: javascript, json, angular, web

I recently upgrade the dependencies within my package.json to their latest versions. The dependencies were outdated by atleast 2 years or maybe more. I''m getting this error whenever I access a page where this data is being called. I'm thinking the issue might be with the updated dependencies and their new functionality. What would be the reason for this?

**This is the portion of the code being referenced in the error**

```js
this.miceBirthdayFilter = (calendarDate: Date): boolean => {
      let birthDates = [];
      this.uniqueValuesForEachAttribute['subject_birth_date'].forEach(date => {
        birthDates.push(date);
      });
      console.log("miceBirthdayFilter in Session " + birthDates.length)
      console.log("calendarDate in miceBirthdayFilter in Session " + calendarDate)
      return birthDates.includes(calendarDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10));
    };
```

**This is the updated package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "pipeline-viewer",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.35",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^12.0.0",
    "@wizpanda/super-gif": "0.0.5",
    "angular-plotly.js": "^4.0.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3", 
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "plotly.js": "^2.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.0.0"
  }
}
```

**This is the old package.json that displays the graphs and charts.**

```json
{
  "name": "pipeline-viewer",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "@wizpanda/super-gif": "0.0.5",
    "angular-plotly.js": "^1.3.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "plotly.js": "^1.49.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the output of your console.log(calendarDate) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return (calendarDate == null ? true : birthDates.includes(calendarDate.toISOString().split('T'))) this fixed the issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Error tells you that the passed value to the function is `null` at least once in your code. `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toISOString')`

Can you double check this by adding some early exit in your function. Something like this.

```
this.miceBirthdayFilter = (calendarDate: Date): boolean => {
      let birthDates = [];
      
      // If calendarDate is null, return false.
      if (!calendarDate) {
        return false 
      }  

      return birthDates.includes(calendarDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10));
    };
```

Comment: Yeah i've used the console.logs to verify that the calendarDate is being passed in as null. What could be the reason for this?